# How do we validate mapping document in oracle to ensure all the information has been provided?

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, mapping, etl

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we validate mapping document in oracle to ensure all the information has been provided. The mapping document should have change logs, maintain datatypes, length, transformation rules etc. as mentioned in the requirement. Please let me know

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: Please read [ask].  Aside from not understanding the question, it is too broad.

Comment: I am sorry.  I did not mean to demean anyone. The actual question being "I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we validate mapping document in oracle to ensure all the information has been provided. The mapping document should have change logs, maintain datatypes, length, transformation rules etc. as mentioned in the requirement. Please let me know"

Answer (score 1):

To ensure a column value must be filled, you can use 'NOT NULL' constraint.